# Do I need to join all foreign keys in sql

Tags: sql

I need to fetch a column from a table which has multiple foreign keys.
This is a basic question, but I am not sure if I need to join all the foreign keys and the tables to fetch a single column ???

Comment: eg. select * from id.testA from testA inner join testB on testA.id = testB.id inner join testC on testA.id = testC.id . Here testB.id and testB.is is a foreign key in testA table.

Comment: Why you don't try it?

Comment: what table is the column you want in?

Comment: I do not have data loaded in the database..there is a dependency on another team for this... but I need to code this piece of code.

Comment: the column i want is in testA table

Comment: The answer is, no you don't.  `select MyColumn from testA` is all you need

Answer (score 2):

If you need no data from other tables joined on foreign keys, then no, you don't need to do any joins in order to fetch a single column, assuming that column is on the select table.

Comment: Thanks.. I too had a slight doubt .So I would join the tables only if I require the columns of the table even though it is a foreign key. So my query should go :  select * from id.testA from testA inner join testB on testA.id = testB.id where testB.id = 100. Am I right to say the above

Comment: Exactly, though your syntax was slightly wrong (testA.id, not id.testA), but otherwise all good :)

Answer (score 0):

You must JOIN a foreign key when you need to obtain the underline value key.

I.E. if you have an EMPLOY table where you have a FK on birth city. If you want to know other info about birth city, stored on CITY table, you must apply a JOIN.

On your table you can have another FK but about your query is not important, so you mustn't apply a JOIN